# Как обрабатывать labels в C++ (CLR)

Tags: c++, c++-cli, ui

Доброе время суток.
Требуется изменять значения каждого Label`a через N время, каким образом можно организовать систему обращения к данным полям в виде:

label[0],label[1],...label[10]

*P.S. В вопросах C++ я не особо силён.*

Comment: эээ... циклом по коллекции?

Answer (score 0):

Не самая понятная формулировка вопроса, но, я думаю, Вы что-то такое имеете в виду:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int label[11];
    int label_len = sizeof(label)/sizeof(int); // количество элементов массива
    for (int i = 0; i < label_len; i++) // цикл инициализации
    {
        label[i] = 1;
        printf("label[%d] = %d\n", i, label[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    sleep(1); // ждем 1 секунду
    for (int i = 0; i < label_len; i++) // цикл изменения каждого значения
    {
        label[i]++;
        printf("label[%d] = %d\n", i, label[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Явное присвоение:

```
int main()
{
    int label0 = 1,
        label1 = 1,
        label2 = 1;
    // ...

    int label[11];
    label[0] = label0;
    label[1] = label1;     
    label[2] = label2;
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я понимаю , вопрос как присвоить label’ам (label0,label1,...,label10) формат массива label[0],label[1],...label[10]

Comment: Ну, например, явно. Сейчас сделаю правку

Comment: А 'label' это не гуи ли элемент имелся в виду?